# Programatically Log User Out [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer-account, customer-group

I have written a module which is basically an observer which triggers on '`customer_save_after_data_object`' the content of this observer basically listens out for when the customers group is changed.

The issue we are having is that if the customers' group is changed when they are logged in it doesn't seem to take effect, meaning that they need to log out of the account and then back in.

My question is, is there a way to log the customer out of their dashboard programmatically when I don't have direct access to the customer session and only the observer data?

Comment: you should get customer session in your observer, try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95558/logout-by-programming-from-observer-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `CustomerTokenServiceInterface`

In your constructor:

```
use Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface;

// ...

/** @var CustomerTokenServiceInterface */
private $tokenService;

public function __construct(CustomerTokenServiceInterface $tokenService) 
{
    $this->tokenService = $tokenService;
}
```

In your code:

```
$this->tokenService->revokeCustomerAccessToken($customerId);
```

You can see an example of this in `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Customer\InvalidateToken` which is the action called by the "Force Sign-In" button for customers in the admin panel.

Don't forget to add `<module name="Magento_Integration" />` to your sequence file, and `magento/module-integration` in your module's composer.json requirements!

Comment: Thanks Navarr, unfortunately this doesn't seem to do the job either. The user continues to be logged in which is a little strange.

Comment: Even when clicking the force log-in button it still doesn't kick the user out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php
namespace Package\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token as Token;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory as TokenModelFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Oauth\Token\CollectionFactory as TokenCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token\RequestThrottler;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class CustomerLogout implements \Package\Modulename\Api\CustomerLogoutInterface
{
    /**
     * Token Model
     *
     * @var TokenModelFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelFactory;

    /**
     * Customer Account Service
     *
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    private $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator
     */
    private $validatorHelper;

    /**
     * Token Collection Factory
     *
     * @var TokenCollectionFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestThrottler
     */
    private $requestThrottler;

    /**
     * Initialize service
     *
     * @param TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory,
        CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->tokenModelCollectionFactory = $tokenModelCollectionFactory;
        $this->validatorHelper = $validatorHelper;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function revokeCustomerAccessToken()
    {
        $customerId = 1;
        $tokenCollection = $this->tokenModelCollectionFactory->create()->addFilterByCustomerId($customerId);
        if ($tokenCollection->getSize() == 0) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('This customer has no tokens.'));
        }
        try {
            foreach ($tokenCollection as $token) {
                $token->setRevoked(1)->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The tokens could not be revoked.'));
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Pro-grammatically logout customer on observer.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Logout implements ObserverInterface {
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataManager
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->cookieMetadataManager = $cookieMetadataManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(PhpCookieManager::class);
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CookieMetadataFactory::class);
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Customer logout action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $lastCustomerId = $this->session->getId();
        $this->session->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())
            ->setLastCustomerId($lastCustomerId);
        if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
            $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
            $metadata->setPath('/');
            $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/logoutSuccess');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

This is the magento core logout functionality, we can use as per our wish.  Just try.