# Magento 2 How we can logout customer from frontend if customer is disabled from admin?

Tags: magento2.3.5

1. Login as a customer in front end side.
2. Then disabled customer from admin panel.
3. Go the front end side and refresh the page,it should be logout automatically.

Please update me if anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a customer from admin only takes effect when the customer next tries to login.

To automatically log the customer out you would have to delete the customer session data on the server, the admin disable customer function cannot do this.

Comment: Yes I understand but based on disabled flagged we can identify if customer idsenable/disabled then we need to delete customer session ? Right ? So for that we have any plugin or observer to achieve this?

Comment: This answer might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192492/programatically-log-user-out-magento-2